# Application crashes when I'm trying to set adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have one working ListView with JSON adapter, but when I'm trying to set another adapter on another listView my application crashes for unknown reason.

I'm using TabLayout and PageAdapter.

When I comment the following line (MainActivity.java, Method 1 below):

```
insListView.setAdapter(mJSONAdapterIns);
```

the application works.

MainActivity getUpdates (Method 1) - WORKS - called in TabFragment1.java:

```
// 4. Access the ListView
                mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_listview);
                // 10. Create a JSONAdapter for the ListView
                mJSONAdapter = new JSONAdapter(MainActivity.this, getLayoutInflater());
                // Set the ListView to use the ArrayAdapter
                mainListView.setAdapter(mJSONAdapter);
```

MainActivity getInstagram() -Method 2 - CRASHING - called in TabFragment2.java:

```
insListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.instagram_listview);
        // 5. Set this activity to react to list items being pressed
        //mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        // 10. Create a JSONAdapter for the ListView
        mJSONAdapterIns = new JSONAdapterIns(MainActivity.this, getLayoutInflater());
        // Set the ListView to use the ArrayAdapter
        insListView.setAdapter(mJSONAdapterIns); //Crashes if this line is NOT commented
```

I'm calling both methods from their Tab Fragments, using the MainActivity.

TabFragment1.java - Works great:

public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fb_list, container, false);
MainActivity king = (MainActivity)getActivity();
king.getUpdates(); // Setting the first list adapter (Method 1)
return v;
```

}

The getUpdates() is updating my first listview and everything is fine.

TabFragment2.java - calling the "crashing" method:

```
public class TabFragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.instagram_list, container, false);

        MainActivity king = (MainActivity)getActivity();
        king.getInstagram(); //Causes crash in the setAdapter line

        return v;
    }
}
```

Logcat error:

```
    1647-1647/il.co.test.test W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2cfab20)
08-26 10:59:45.050    1647-1647/il.co.test.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: il.co.test.test, PID: 1647
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at il.co.test.test.MainActivity.getInstagram(MainActivity.java:175)
            at il.co.test.test.TabFragment2.onCreateView(TabFragment2.java:20)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1016)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:535)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 10:59:59.010    1647-1647/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1647 SIG: 9
```

How I can fix this crash?

Edit 1:
Was trying to add the following line in Method 2 and commenting the setAdapter.

```
TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x1);
        test.setText("TEST");
```

Application crashed too.

Seem like findViewById returns NULL. why?

***instagram_list.xml***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/x1"
        android:text="TEST"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <!-- List whose dataset is defined in code with an adapter -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/instagram_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="20.0sp"

        />


</LinearLayout>
```

New logcat after Prerak's answer:

```
08-26 11:59:12.720    1599-1599/il.co.test.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: il.co.test.test, PID: 1599
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
            at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4532)
            at il.co.test.test.MainActivity.getInstagram(MainActivity.java:172)
            at il.co.test.test.TabFragment2.onCreateView(TabFragment2.java:25)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1016)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:535)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit
```

Comment: Please add your logcat too.

Comment: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: sss, PID: 1662
    java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: One of the variables you are using is null, it's impossible to know which one with the information you've given

Comment: Add complete logcat pertaining to the exception.

Comment: @ParagKadam I added the complete logcat.

Comment: @TimCastelijns What information do you need..?

Comment: if findViewById(id) is null, is because not exist a view for that id in your layout. check your setContentView(layout)

Comment: Which is the line 175 in your `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: @PrerakSola the line causes the crash, `insListView.setAdapter(mJSONAdapterIns);`

Comment: @juanhl it doesn't make sense since im using tab fragments, this is how I'm calling Method 2(to set the second listview) `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.instagram_list, container, false);

        MainActivity king = (MainActivity)getActivity();
        king.getInstagram();
        
        return v;
    }`  king.getInstagram(); is Method 2 above (question body). I set the content view only once in the beginning of MainActivity onCreate

Comment: @PrerakSola added in question body

Comment: Post your relevant code in the question and classes, it is imposible know where you get that nullpointer without a context where looking for.

Comment: @juanhl I think I posted all the relevant code, if there is something else I can post please let me know

Comment: What is the meaning of "Tab #1 List adapter (Method 1):" "Tab #2 List Adapter" where is that code?

Comment: Pot your `MainActivity.java` file. Do you set both the adapters in the same file?

Comment: @juanhl I updated my question body, let me know if you can understand now.

Comment: @PrerakSola Yes, I update both in my MainActivity with 2 different methods called in different tab fragments, please check the question body, I updated it to be clearer. Please let me know if you understand what happens.

Comment: Your `MainActivity` does not know `R.id.instagram_listview`. So, it is throwing the `NullPointerException`. Set the adapter in `Tabfragment2`.

Comment: post your main_activity layout and we will see that R.id.instagram_listview dont exists in that layout

Comment: @PrerakSola so how does it know when I'm calling it from TabFragment1?

Comment: @juanhl ofcourse it don't, it's in instagram_list.xml

Comment: The XML corresponding to `MainActivity.java` must be having a listview with the id `main_listview`. So that's why it is able to fetch it.

Comment: @PrerakSola hmm fine, but in the fragment I can't use the findViewById to get the list..

Comment: You need use "v.findViewById(id)" in your onCreateView Fragment method, I think that you are missing something :P, from an activity you can access Views in fragments which has been inflated previusly, if the fragment was replaced, you couldn't find your child fragments views from the activity.

Comment: This is the reason I didn't want to implement the method in the fragment itself, it caused alot of errors with the view. What about the `getLayoutInflater()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inflate your`instagram_list.xml` in your `MainActivity.java` like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.instagram_list, null);
```

After that, instantiate your `ListView` like

```
insListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.instagram_listview);
```

So the complete code of `getInstagram()` method will be:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.instagram_list, null);
insListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.instagram_listview);

mJSONAdapterIns = new JSONAdapterIns(MainActivity.this, getLayoutInflater());
insListView.setAdapter(mJSONAdapterIns);
```

Or the other method as @juanhl suggested in comment could be passing the `view` from `TabFragment2` to the `getInstagram()` method like below:

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.instagram_list, container, false);
MainActivity king = (MainActivity)getActivity();
king.getInstagram(v); //Pass the view as an agruement
```

And in your `getInstagram()` method you can do like this:

```
public void getInstagram(View v)
{
   insListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.instagram_listview);

   mJSONAdapterIns = new JSONAdapterIns(MainActivity.this, getLayoutInflater());
   insListView.setAdapter(mJSONAdapterIns);    
}
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work, He needs get the view from the fragment dont inflate another new.

Comment: I was sure it's going to work, but another error occured, I can't use the system services

Comment: @juanhl: Yes, that can also be done. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @TheUnreal: Try the second approach. It's more better than the first one.

Comment: Glad to help... Happy coding .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Get the `ListView` directly from your fragment.

```
private ListView insListView ;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.instagram_list, container, false);

    insListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.instagram_listview);
    //MainActivity king = (MainActivity)getActivity();
    //king.getInstagram(); //Causes crash in the setAdapter line

    return v;
}
```

Search how communicating fragments with activities, maybe it helps you.